# SQL: Get Number of First Place Scores of User

Tags: php, mysql

I have a score table that has the following stucture:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_scores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `game_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=329 ;
```

I am trying to generate a list of top players ordered by the number of first place high scores they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Higher scores are better. (Otherwise, use `MIN` instead of `MAX`)
- The issue here is there are multiple games, denoted by `game_id`. Therefore each `game_id` should have its own first-place user(s)

You can get first-place scores by:

```
SELECT MAX(score) score, game_id
FROM game_scores
GROUP BY game_id
```

You can then get users with first-place scores by joining on this aggregate. This should also properly include ties:

```
SELECT s.user_id
FROM game_scores s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(score) score, game_id
    FROM game_scores
    GROUP BY game_id
) fp ON s.game_id = fp.game_id AND s.score = fp.score
```

You can then count these up for each user and order by the count:

```
SELECT s.user_id, COUNT(*) first_place_scores
FROM game_scores s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(score) score, game_id
    FROM game_scores
    GROUP BY game_id
) fp ON s.game_id = fp.game_id AND s.score = fp.score
GROUP BY s.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, really helped me understand it.  Was stuck for awhile!

Comment: Sure thing. A lot of times complicated SQL queries are just built up from little parts. It helps to just start small and build around that until you get what you want.

Comment: @lc. perfect explanation given rather than just posting the answer

Comment: Mind if I probe your brain again?  What if some games have a highscore that is set by the lowest score?  Would there be two inner joins?  I see that your assumption is that its either or, but how to handle both?

Comment: You could use a case based on a field in your game descriptor table (assuming you have one). Something like `CASE WHEN game.islowscore_good = 1 THEN MIN(score) ELSE MAX(score) END`

Comment: Thanks! You showing me the ways of MySQL, CASE is what I was looking for.  I had a `score_type` row in my game table, was trying to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a score of 1 means high score, the following should do what you want:

```sql
SELECT count(user_id), user_id FROM game_scores WHERE score="1" GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count(user_id) DESC
```